# Angular 13: Angular Material 13 custom theme throwing error

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, angular13

I have custom theme pallet for my project which is working fine with version `^12.2.13` of the angular material but not with `^13.2.3`. Below is my SCSS for custom theming:

**custome-mat-theme.scss**

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$cust-blue: (primary: #002a5c, contrast: (primary: #ffffff));
$cust-gold: (accent: #989100, contrast: (accent: #ffffff));
$primary: mat-palette($cust-blue, primary);
$accent: mat-palette($cust-gold, accent);

$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent);

@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

**angular.json**

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
  "./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
  "src/styles.css",
  "src/assets/css/custom-mat-theme.scss"
]
```

**Error**

> ./src/assets/css/custom-mat-theme.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[1]!./src/assets/css/custom-mat-theme.scss
>
> - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: 'Hue "100" does
>   not exist in palette. Available hues are: primary, contrast'    ╷ 55 │
>   lighter: _get-color-from-palette($base-palette, $lighter),    │
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ╵
>   node_modules@angular\material\core\theming_theming.scss 55:14
>   define-palette()
>   node_modules@angular\material\core\theming_theming-deprecated.scss
>   16:11  palette()   src\assets\css\custom-mat-theme.scss 6:11
>   root stylesheet

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this?

Comment: There were some changes in last versions and `@use` should be used instead of `@import` you can check the tutorial for theming [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming). More to `SCSS modules` [here](https://css-tricks.com/introducing-sass-modules/). Not sure if this helps. I will try to reproduce the error.

Comment: I have tried using "@use" but that didn't help. Also tried looking into the official documentation but I've less knowledge about SCSS

Comment: It seems that from v13 all palette hue values must be defined. Check this discussion https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24250

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov can you provide a sample on how to define all the hues in the palette as I don't require all the hues for my project?

Comment: @BarefacedBear it will look like this https://github.com/angular-university/angular-material-course/blob/master/src/styles.scss

Comment: @BarefacedBear could you solve the problem with provided sample?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that material needs at least hue: 100, hue 500 and hue 700 (probably for functions like lighter etc).

I had the same problem as you, I only defined that hue 500. I then set hue 100 and hue 700 for each color and it solved my problem. Personally, for beginning, I used the same color for the three hue.

Comment: What exactly did you change or add for hue: 100?